# Python custom function

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I have been working at learning Python over the last week and it has been going really well, however I have now been introduced to custom functions and I sort of hit a wall.  While I understand the basics of it, such as:

```
def helloworld():
    print("Hello World!")

helloworld()
```

I know this will print "Hello World!".

However, when it comes to getting information from one function to another, I find that confusing.  ie:  function1 and function2 have to work together to perform a task.   Also, when to use the `return` command.

Lastly, when I have a list or a dictionary inside of a function.  I'll make something up just as an example.

```
def my_function():
    my_dict = {"Key1":Value1,
              "Key2":Value2,
              "Key3":Value3,
              "Key4":Value4,}
```

How would I access the key/value and be able to change them from outside of the function?  ie: If I had a program that let you input/output player stats or a character attributes in a video game.

I understand bits and pieces of this, it just confuses me when they have different functions calling on each other.

Also, since this was my first encounter with the custom functions.  Is this really ambitious to pursue and this could be the reason for all of my confusion?  Since this is the most complex program I have seen yet.

Comment: Always use return inside a  function.

Comment: I think you'll have to be more specific.  Can you give an example of something you might want to do?

Comment: @SantoshKumar I think that's a good guideline, but not every function should use `return`.  A good example is functions that only use `print`.

Comment: I'll post something as an example.  =]

Comment: @SethMMorton we can always use `print(my_function)` for that condition.

Comment: it's not too ambitious! Stick with it, and you'll get the hang of Python :) I had these problems too when I was learning my first programming language. Cool project BTW.

Comment: @SantoshKumar OK, I agree with your first point. I'm not sure where the comment about separate return values came from...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Functions` in python can be both, a regular `procedure` and a `function` with a return value. Actually, every Python's function will return a value, which might be `None`.

If a return statement is not present, then your function will be executed completely and leave normally following the code flow, yielding `None` as a return value.

```
def foo():
    pass
foo() == None
>>> True
```

If you have a `return` statement inside your function. The return value will be the **return value of the expression following it**. For example you may have `return None` and you'll be explicitly returning `None`. You can also have `return` without anything else and there you'll be implicitly returning `None`, or, you can have `return 3` and you'll be returning value 3. This may grow in complexity.

```
def foo():
   print('hello')
   return
   print('world')

foo()
>>>'hello'

def add(a,b):
    return a + b
add(3,4)
>>>7
```

If you want a dictionary (or any object) you created inside a function, just return it:

```
def my_function():
    my_dict = {"Key1":Value1,
              "Key2":Value2,
              "Key3":Value3,
              "Key4":Value4,}
    return my_dict
d = my_function()
d['Key1']
>>> Value1
```

Those are the basics of function calling. There's even more. There are functions that return functions (also treated as decorators. You can even return multiple values (not really, you'll be just returning a tuple) and a lot a fun stuff :)

```
def two_values():
    return 3,4
a,b = two_values()
print(a)
>>>3
print(b)
>>>4
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: In the `def foo()` example, where it is `return` `print("world")` what would the purpose of that be, also, how would you actually have the function print that instance of "world"?

Comment: It's purpose is to show you that the `return` statement finished the function execution. Anything under it is not executed (it's pretty clear though but still, just wanted to show)

Comment: Oh okay, thank you.  So the `print("world")` after `return` would never be executed and/or inaccessible?

Comment: Right, clever text editors will warn you about inaccessible code.

Answer (score 3):

The primary way to pass information between functions is with arguments and return values. Functions can't see each other's variables. You might think that after

```
def my_function():
    my_dict = {"Key1":Value1,
              "Key2":Value2,
              "Key3":Value3,
              "Key4":Value4,}
my_function()
```

`my_dict` would have a value that other functions would be able to see, but it turns out that's a really brittle way to design a language. Every time you call `my_function`, `my_dict` would lose its old value, even if you were still using it. Also, you'd have to know all the names used by every function in the system when picking the names to use when writing a new function, and the whole thing would rapidly become unmanageable. Python doesn't work that way; I can't think of any languages that do.

Instead, if a function needs to make information available to its caller, `return` the thing its caller needs to see:

```
def my_function():
    return {"Key1":"Value1",
            "Key2":"Value2",
            "Key3":"Value3",
            "Key4":"Value4",}
print(my_function()['Key1']) # Prints Value1
```

Note that a function ends when its execution hits a `return` statement (even if it's in the middle of a loop); you can't execute one return now, one return later, keep going, and return two things when you hit the end of the function. If you want to do that, keep a list of things you want to return and return the list when you're done.

Answer (score 2):

You send information **into** and **out of** functions with **arguments** and **return values**, respectively. This function, for example:

```
def square(number):
    """Return the square of a number."""
    return number * number
```

... recieves information through the `number` argument, and sends information back with the `return ...` statement. You can use it like this:

```
>>> x = square(7)
>>> print(x)
49
```

As you can see, we passed the value `7` to the function, and it returned the value `49` (which we stored in the variable `x`).

Now, lets say we have another function:

```
def halve(number):
    """Return half of a number."""
    return number / 2.0
```

We can send information between two functions in a couple of different ways.

1. Use a temporary variable:

   ```
   >>> tmp = square(6)
   >>> halve(tmp)
   18.0
   ```
2. use the first function directly as an argument to the second:

   ```
   >>> halve(square(8))
   32.0
   ```

Which of those you use will depend partly on personal taste, and partly on how complicated the thing you're trying to do is.

Even though they have the same name, the `number` variables inside `square()` and `halve()` are completely separate from each other, and they're invisible outside those functions:

```
>>> number
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'number' is not defined
```

So, it's actually impossible to "see" the variable `my_dict` in your example function. What you would normally do is something like this:

```
def my_function(my_dict):
    # do something with my_dict
    return my_dict
```

... and define `my_dict` outside the function.

(It's actually a little bit more complicated than that - `dict` objects are *mutable* (which just means they can change), so often you don't actually need to return them. However, for the time being it's probably best to get used to returning everything, just to be safe).